# iOS: Instance of class returns a view, this view has buttons that don't work

Tags: ios

I have a class, which creates a view with a button. In another view controller I create an instance of this, and call the create method, which returns the view with the button inside, and displays it in the view controller.

Whenever I try to press the button, the program crashes however.

Here is the class which I create an instance of:

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

- (UIView*)createView:(int)x  y:(int)y {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 75)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(testMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [view addSubview:button];

    return view;
}

- (void)testMethod {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}

@end
```

And here is when I create an instance of it in the other View Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Add color picker to screen
    Test *testView = [[Test alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview: [testView createView:100 y:100]];
}
```

Anybody know if this is even possible? or what I may be doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is because you have made the `Test` instance the button handler. However, the `Test` instance is deallocated at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method. So the button is left pointing to a deallocated handler. When the button is pressed, the app crashes because the `Test` instance is gone.

Update your view controller code so the `Test` instance is kept in an instance variable instead of a local variable in the `viewDidLoad` method. This will fix the crash.

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: @rmaddy, I got another questionf or ya, is there a way so that when I click that button, it changes the value of a variable inside of the ViewController class?

Comment: That's really a whole separate question beyond the scope of this one. Basically you need to define a protocol and delegate for your `Test` class. Then the view controller can be the delegate. When notified of the button press, the view controller can do whatever is appropriate. Post a new question of you need more help with that.